# Calling an API Function from DINPUT.Dll Using Delphi Or Pascal

Tags: delphi, directinput

I have a program which uses an API from dinput.dll (Direct Input), I have monitored it and the result is this:

API Name: DirectInputCreateEx
Module Name: C:\Windows\system32\DINPUT.dll

And about another program which uses Direct Input:

API Name: DirectInputCreateA
Module Name: C:\Windows\system32\DINPUT.dll

This API will update this registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\DirectInput

I want to know How can I use Delphi to write a code which ONLY call this API for DirectInput dll?

Any Help is really appreciated...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070459/delphi-working-with-dlls-for-beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call Direct Input you will need a Delphi translation of the header file. The best such translation, to my knowledge, is available from the [Clootie graphics pages](http://www.clootie.ru/delphi/download_dx90.html#Headers).

You need to use the `DirectInput.pas` header translation.

As for writing a program that does not show a Window, here's the simplest template:

```
program MyProgram;
begin
  //write your program's code here
end.
```

You state in a comment that the only function you wish to call is `DirectInputCreateEx`. To call that function you need the following import declaration:

```
function DirectInputCreateEx(hinst: THandle; dwVersion: DWORD; 
  const riidltf: TGUID; out ppvOut; punkOuter: IUnknown): HResult; 
  stdcall; external 'dinput.dll';
```

Comment: Needs a period instead of a semicolon

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. How would I even know what you write? You didn't say what you wanted to do. Make a start yourself and ask for help when you get stuck.

Comment: Ok, Your answer can help me a lot man :) I have change my question a little :)

Comment: Your question is getting less clear to me. I answered how to call DirectInput from Delphi, but now you are talking about registry? I'm very confused.

Comment: Hi David, I just want to use only DirectInputCreateEx API from dinput.dll, I do not want to use any other APIs, I think Direct Input header file has too many extra API. I just one to use one, without using nay extra info and any extra direct x API. How to do that?

Comment: OK, I answered that but I find it hard to imagine that's all you need to call. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Hi David, Really I just want to update that registry key, why? Because I want to get the list of connected joysticks with their IDs. ePSXe (PS1 Emu) will use the API which I have witten in main question. So the registry will update and I can see the connected joysticks. Just this. So Can you help me again David?

Comment: Another Thing David, if you delete that reg key, and execute this API, it will be created again, no joystick is needed for testing. But I do not know how to make it :(

Comment: I don't think this question can be salvaged easily. You are now asking completely different questions in comments. You need to ask a new question. However please do not ask it as you have done here. Don't present your proposed solution. Present the underlying problem and ask for a solution.